# On off button inside a Toggle Button

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, button, material-design

I need a toggle button which will also work like an ON/OFF button. That is to say 
- it will slide right or left on click. 
- it will be ON/OFF it it's current position on click

To say in other words, it is an ON/OFF switch with left or right slide animations. Also I need some event when it moves to right or left.

Any idea how to do will be appreciated.

Comment: Use this library  https://github.com/zcweng/SwitchButton

Comment: What is the problem with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html

Comment: Good question. I mean on tap it will not slide to right from left. It will just go OFF from ON while still on the left side. It will only go right on slide. These are just for my case..